# Solidity Visibility with mappings

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I was playing around with visibility and mapping in solidity and came across something i am trying to understand better.  One with an internal visibility and the other public. I deployed them and got two different working results.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Marketplace {
    mapping (uint => string) internal products; 

 function writeproduct(uint _index, string memory _product) public{
        products[_index] = _product;
    }
 function readproduct(uint _index) public view returns(string memory) {
       return products[_index];
     }
}
```

[picture showing code with internal visibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssaaT.png)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Marketplace {
    mapping (uint => string) internal products; 

 function writeproduct(uint _index, string memory _product) public{
        products[_index] = _product;
    }
 function readproduct(uint _index) public view returns(string memory) {
       return products[_index];
     }
}
```

[picture showing code with public visibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hU82.png)

After seeing this i decided to remove the readproduct function to see what happens and this is what i got. Please help me get a better understanding.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Marketplace {
    mapping (uint => string) public products; 

 function writeproduct(uint _index, string memory _product) public{
        products[_index] = _product;
    }
}
```

This is what i got.
[After removing the readproduct function it still worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjN2x.png)

Answer (score 0):

When visibility is internal you can't access the variable you have to make a getter function to access it.

In your case, you made a `readproduct` function to access the value of `products` when its visibility was `internal`. But when the visibility is `public`, you don't need a getter function you can access it directly, the solidity compiler makes one for you.

But specifically for mappings to access them via scripts in hardhat, you must have to have a getter function no matter the visibility, but it will be visible on remix or etherscan (obv. if the contract is verified). Thats what I've experienced.

Answer (score 0):

if the visibility is `public`, solidity will assign a getter function for the public variables. That is why you see a getter function. But in the case of mapping and array, that getter function will not return the entire object. Instead you have to enter a key for the mapping, index for the array and you get the single item.

In case of `internal` visibility, you cannot access those variables externally. They are accessible from the functions inside the current contract  or child contracts that derive from the current contract.